# how to use fetchjsonp abort signal ? fetchjsonp( url, {signal})?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need jsonp, but fetch() api do not provide jsonp option. 
So I found fetch-jsonp [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp)

However, the standard fetch have optional abort.signal feature.

```
abortController = new AbortController()
signal = abortController.signal

fetch( url, {signal})
```

see fetch signal api at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

fetch-jsonp [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) seems not provide abort.signal option

how do I do can make use of

```
 fetchjsonp( url, {signal})
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is a dirty, dirty hack. It works by injecting a `<script>` element into the page.

You can't abort it because it isn't designed to be a proper HTTP API.

Since CORS came around in 2009 there really isn't a good reason for any web service to use it.

If you can, fix the web service so it supports JSON and CORS instead of JSONP.

Otherwise, you will probably need to build your own JSONP library. The closest you can really come to aborting a request is to change the callback function after the event.

So you'd do something along the lines of:

```
const id = generate_a_unique_id();
window[`callback_${id}`] = function(data) { /* do something with data */ };
const url = `http://example.com/jsonp?callback=callback_${id}`;
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

and then to abort it:

```
window[`callback_${id}`] = function () { /* do nothing */ };
```